# Python pandas read_hdf WHERE term not functioning as expected

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5storage

I'm trying to do a simple filter on an HDF5-formatted table, using Python pandas. Works fine when I query by the 'subject' column alone:

```
> df_test = pd.read_hdf(result_file, where=['subject==andrew'])
> print(df_test)
```

Which gives the output:

```
        subject condition        time  pupil_diam  luminance   gaze_x  gaze_y
 ...        ...       ...         ...         ...        ...      ...     ...
 180519  andrew     light  5885480250        2.50   0.768958  1723.85  267.11
 180520  andrew     light  5885482247        2.50   0.769088  1723.33  266.81
 180521  andrew     light  5885484249        2.51   0.769405  1718.93  267.91
```

Also works when I query by the 'luminance' column alone:

```
> df_test = pd.read_hdf(params['result_file'], where=['luminance>0'])
> print(df_test)


        subject condition        time  pupil_diam  luminance  gaze_x  gaze_y
 79005     mary     light  3813968998        3.22   0.225418  257.11  761.28
 79006     mary     light  3813970992        3.22   0.227119  256.38  761.13
 79007     mary     light  3813972992        3.21   0.227119  256.13  760.53
 ...        ...       ...         ...         ...        ...      ...     ...
```

But putting these together with an "&" gives an empty result (as you can see above, there are definitely rows where both conditions are true):

```
> df_test = pd.read_hdf(params['result_file'], where=['subject==andrew & luminance>0'])
> print(df_test)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [subject, condition, time, pupil_diam, luminance, gaze_x, gaze_y]
Index: []
```

Although this query works when I use:

```
> df_test = pd.read_hdf(params['result_file'], where=['subject==mary & luminance>0'])
> print(df_test)

       subject condition        time  pupil_diam  luminance  gaze_x  gaze_y
79005     mary     light  3813968998        3.22   0.225418  257.11  761.28
79006     mary     light  3813970992        3.22   0.227119  256.38  761.13
79007     mary     light  3813972992        3.21   0.227119  256.13  760.53
...        ...       ...         ...         ...        ...      ...     ...
```

New to pandas, so it could be I'm missing something wrt. syntax, but haven't yet found a decent solution/explanation in the docs or online forums...